# Hazelcast - query collections of Map values

Tags: hazelcast, distributed-cache, hazelcast-imap

Assume I have the following as the value in an IMap:

```
public class Employee{
  public int empId;
  public List<String> categories;

  public List<String> getCategories(){
    return this.categories;
  }
}
```

I would like to find all employees that belong to category "Sales". Also, I would like to create an index on getCategories() so that the query returns fast. There seems to be no Predicate available to do this. How do I go about achieving this? It seems like I will have to write a Predicate to do this. Is there example code I can look at that would show me how to build a predicate that uses an index ?

Comment: @pveentjer, Could you please answer this question ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I currently see this happening is to denormalize the data model and use something like a IMap and the following as value:

class EmployeeCategory{int employeeId, String category}

And put an index on category.

It is somewhere on the backlog to provide more advances indices that should be able to do this out of the box.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there any backlog to add index to multimaps as well ? I think it would be of immense help in scenarios like this.

Comment: Afaik there no such issue. Feel free to make a github ticket or to make an implementation yourself :)

Comment: Send me the secret code to http://hazelcast.org/t-shirts/ and I'll get the implementation done ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried by iterating the List to a separate Imap and then querying it in the client.

```
IMap<String,ArrayList< categories >> cache=hazelcastInstance.getMap("cache");                   
        IMap<String, categories> cachemodified = hazelcastInstance.getMap("cachemodified") ;        
        int[] idx = { 0 };
        xref.get("urkey").forEach(cachefelement ->{
            cachemodified.put(String.valueOf(idx[0]++),cachefelement);
        });
        Predicate p = Predicates.equal("categoryId", "SearchValue");
        Collection<categories> result = cachemodified.values(p);
```